# Replacing google slides images using slides api

Tags: python, service-accounts, presentation, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have the following scripts to update the images in google slides, it works fine but sometimes it gives me 400 error, service account has a write permission to the drive/images and the presentation

```
image_mappings = {
    "id_in_presenation": "name_of_the_image",
    "id_in_presenation1": "name_of_the_image1",
}

# listing .png files 
def get_png_files(drive_folder_id, drive_service):
    query = f"'{drive_folder_id}' in parents and mimeType='image/png'"
    results = drive_service.files().list(q=query, supportsAllDrives=True, fields="files(id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink)").execute()
    drive_png_files = results.get('files', [])
    print('drive_png_files', drive_png_files)
    return drive_png_files`


# updating images in slides

def update_images_in_slides(drive_png_files, slides_service, presentation_id):
    """
    Updates images in a Google Slides presentation.

    Args:
    drive_png_files: A list of .png files from Google Drive.
    slides_service: The authenticated Google Slides service object.
    presentation_id: The ID of the presentation to update.
    """

    requests = []
    for slide_image_id, new_image_name in info.image_mappings.items():
        drive_file = next((item for item in drive_png_files if item['name'] == new_image_name), None)
        if drive_file:
            requests.append({
                'replaceImage': {
                    'imageObjectId': slide_image_id,
                    'imageReplaceMethod': 'CENTER_INSIDE',
                    'url': f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={drive_file["id"]}'
                }
            })
    if requests:
        body = {'requests': requests}
        try:
            response = slides_service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body).execute()
            time.sleep(10)
            print(f"\nUpdated the slide: {response}")
        except Exception as exc:
            raise ValueError(f"Failed to update the presentation.") from exc
```

gave editor and writer access permission to the service account for the drives, images, presentation did not help

Comment: Based on your question it works however there are time that it doesn't. Can you give more information about this? Do you see a pattern if it is a periodic issue then it means that your code is working correctly. You might want to look at some pattern, requirements in order for you to make this work. You can always share how do you reproduce the issue, what are the steps you are taking before it gets fixed.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I proposed an answer by guessing your situation. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct and my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I guessed the following issues.

1. Image files that are not publicly shared might be included.
2. Image files that are over the maximum image size might be included. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#replaceimagerequest)

When these issues occur, an error of the status code 400 occurs. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual error message from your question. When my guess was correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your function `update_images_in_slides` is modified.

**In order to use Drive API, `drive_service` is added to the last argument. Please be careful about this.**

```py
def update_images_in_slides(drive_png_files, slides_service, presentation_id, drive_service):
    """
    Updates images in a Google Slides presentation.

    Args:
    drive_png_files: A list of .png files from Google Drive.
    slides_service: The authenticated Google Slides service object.
    presentation_id: The ID of the presentation to update.
    """

    # Images are publicly shared for inserting to Slide.
    batch1 = drive_service.new_batch_http_request()
    for e in drive_png_files:
        batch1.add(drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=e["id"], body={"type": "anyone", "role": "reader"}, supportsAllDrives=True))
    batch1.execute()

    requests = []
    for slide_image_id, new_image_name in info.image_mappings.items():
        drive_file = next((item for item in drive_png_files if item['name'] == new_image_name), None)
        if drive_file:
            requests.append({
                'replaceImage': {
                    'imageObjectId': slide_image_id,
                    'imageReplaceMethod': 'CENTER_INSIDE',
                    # 'url': f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={drive_file["id"]}'
                    'url': f'https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id={drive_file["id"]}'
                }
            })
    if requests:
        body = {'requests': requests}
        try:
            response = slides_service.presentations().batchUpdate(presentationId=presentation_id, body=body).execute()
            time.sleep(10)
            print(f"\nUpdated the slide: {response}")
        except Exception as exc:
            raise ValueError(f"Failed to update the presentation.") from exc

    # Permission of publicly shared images is removed.
    batch2 = drive_service.new_batch_http_request()
    for e in drive_png_files:
        batch2.add(drive_service.permissions().delete(fileId=e["id"], permissionId="anyoneWithLink", supportsAllDrives=True))
    batch2.execute()
```

- When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that the script worked without errors.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your values of `drive_png_files, slides_service, presentation_id, drive_service` and `info.image_mappings` are valid values. Please be careful about this.
- In this modification, the following flow is used.

  1. Image files are publicly shared.
  2. Put the publicly shared images on Slide.
  3. Permissions of public sharing are removed.
- I cannot know your current scopes. So, when an error is related to the scopes, please add a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to your current scope, and test it again. Please be careful about this.
- If the image sizes of all images are varied sizes, I guess that `'url': f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={drive_file["id"]}'` might be able to be used.

#### Reference

- [ReplaceImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#replaceimagerequest)

Comment: hi @tanaike, a quick question, for the shared drives what changes should i make ?

Comment: @nisakova About your new question of `hi @tanaike, a quick question, for the shared drives what changes should i make ?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Bbecause my proposed script can use the files in the shared drive. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: thank you for your response, if I use my own google drive it works perfectly, but whenever I use shared google drive, its failing to update the slides images and giving me 400 error code, its failing to change the permission for the .png files in shared google drive

Comment: @nisakova Thank you for replying. Can you post it a a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: hi @tanaike, thank you for replying, created new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77870655/replacing-google-slides-images-using-slides-api-in-shared-google-drives